# Looking at the mouse position in a top down Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity, mouse

I'm trying to make a simple top down game where the player looks at wherever the mouse is pointed.  The player is only going to rotate on the Y axis.

Here's what I have so far but I can't seem to get it working.

```
private void RotateToMouse()
{   
    //Veriables
    Vector3 ScreenMouse;
    Vector3 ShipPos;

    //Get Mouse Point ON screen
    ScreenMouse.x  = Input.mousePosition.x;
    ScreenMouse.y  = Input.mousePosition.y;
    ScreenMouse.z  = 1;

    //Get Mouse Point In World
    WorldMouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(ScreenMouse);
    //Get Ship Position
    ShipPos = transform.position;

    //Get Angle Of Mouse From Ship Position
    Angle = Mathf.Atan2(ShipPos.z - WorldMouse.z,ShipPos.x - WorldMouse.x) * 180 / Mathf.PI;

    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,Angle,0);        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Atan2, I would suggest using the built in function [`Transform.LookAt`](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

So, after you get `WorldMouse`, just do `transform.LookAt( WorldMouse );`.

You *might* have to set `WorldMouse.y` equal to `transform.position.y`, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: still doesn't work. The object rotates small amounts but Isn't looking at the Mouse, I tried both with and without WorldMouse.y equal to the objects y position. any other suggestions ?

Comment: I Created a new object, and set its position to be WorldMouse. the object does not follow the mouse, I think the problem has something to do with getting the WorldMouse Position from the Screen Mouse.

Comment: @Dusty what was "the problem"?

Comment: the Camera needs to be centered above the Object